# How do you prevent a CSS animation from rerunning when the display property changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Given an element that has a CSS animation that changes `opacity`, why does the animation get rerun when the `display` property changes? How do I stop this from happening?

Example code:

HTML

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.foo {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 600ms forwards 0ms ease;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".foo").toggleClass("hidden")
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s68yf/1)

The behavior I am expecting to see is that the animation runs when the DOM renders, but does not rerun when the display property is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to add a class when the button gets clicked that overwrites the animation property.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s68yf/2/)

```js
$(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".foo").addClass('finished').toggleClass("hidden")
    })
})
```

```css
.foo.finished {
    -webkit-animation: none;
}
```

---

Another option would be to hide it with `position: relative` instead of changing `display`:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s68yf/8/)

```css
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -99999px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Curious. It seems that Chrome is acting as if changing from `display: none` to `block` was the same as adding the element to the DOM. I tried it in Firefox ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s68yf/5/)), and it works as one would expect. IE, however, does the same as Chrome. One could think that Firefox's behaviour is the correct, but, thinking about it, `display: none` is like taking the node form the layout and rendering trees, so, if the page loads with the object with `display: none`, and then it changes to `block`, I would expect to see the animation.

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.foo {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    animation: fade-in 3000ms forwards 0ms ease;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do that.. its a bit hacky but you can remove that class and add another class that doesn't have the animation. `$("#my_foo").removeClass("foo").addClass("your_foo");`

http://jsfiddle.net/s68yf/6/